# Some "non usual characters" encoded incorrectly when being scraped using Scrapy

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, scrapy

I've used Scrapy to get Movies data, but some of them have special characters which are encoded improperly.

As an example there's a movie that has a link in a website:
[Pokémon: Detective Pikachu](/movie/Pokemon-Detective-Pikachu-(2019)#tab=summary)

The conflict is with the "é" character when getting the movie name.

All the data is added to a json file using the terminal command "scrapy crawl movie -o movies.json"

If in Scrapy's settings.py, non FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING is provided, the word Pokémon, is written in the json file as `"Pok\u00e9mon"`

If FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8' is used, the name is being written as "PokÃ©mon"

The parse method in the spider is as follows:

```
def parse(self, response):

    base_link = 'http://www.the-numbers.com'
    rows_in_big_table = response.xpath("//table/tr") 

    movie_name = onerow.xpath('td/b/a/text()').extract()[0]

    movie_item['movie_name'] = movie_name

    yield movie_budget_item

    next_page = 
    response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]/a[@class="active"]/following- 
    sibling::a/@href').get()

    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

As an extra information, I have this information of the json file where the information is parsed:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='movie.json' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

The goal is to get the character `"é"` in the word `"Pokémon"`.

How would you tackle this problem and why is this happening, I've been reading lots of info about encoding and in Python documentation but I can find a solution.

I've also tried to use `"unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', 'Pok\u00e9mon')"` but without success.

I appreciate your help! Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you post the "string" extracted with the word Pokemon? (s = your variable) Also post print(s) and print(repr(s)) . I usually solve this kind of problems with html_extracted.encode("utf-8"). Pd: I think the problem is on file save and the encoding='cp1252'

Comment: It's probably the encoding of your .json file. Can you add your pipeline code?

Comment: change your encoding type - try either `utf-8` or `ISO-5589-1` and that should do the trick. If you try to print your string you will see it prints out normally because of the encoding used by python itself.

Comment: How are you looking at the data? given the `cp1252` in the encoding it seems like you are using Windows. Many windows applications will just use the "default" encoding cp1252 so if oyu save an utf-8 you should somehow tell your application to open it as utf-8, seeing weird characters if opened without this it's expected. You can try to set `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING` to `cp1252`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use encoding [**ISO-8859-1**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
import scrapy
from bad_encoding.items import BadEncodingItem


class MoviesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'movies'
    allowed_domains = ['www.the-numbers.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/domestic/all-movies/cumulative/all-time/301'
    ]

    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'ISO-8859-1'}

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//table/tbody/tr'):
            items = BadEncodingItem()
            items['Rank'] = row.xpath('.//td[1]/text()').get()
            items['Released'] = row.xpath('.//td[2]/a/text()').get()
            items['Movie'] = row.xpath('.//td[3]/b/a/text()').get()
            items['Domestic'] = row.xpath('.//td[4]/text()').get()
            items['International'] = row.xpath('.//td[5]/text()').get()
            items['Worldwide'] = row.xpath('.//td[6]/text()').get()

            yield items
```

And this is my json file

[image]

Comment: Very handy this feature of custom encoding settings! Top answer :)